# Invalid values not breaking, results not being shown

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

My VB.NET program is giving me two errors:

1. It does not break when I enter a negative value or 0.
2. It does not show me the total values.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
Enter deposit amount: 300
Another (y or n)? y
Enter deposit amount: -1
Amount cannot be zero or negative.
```

My Code:

```
 Module Module1

 Sub Main()
    Dim userResponse As Char
    Dim depositAmount As Decimal
    Dim totalDeposits As Decimal

    Dim depositCount As Integer
    Dim averageDeposit As Decimal
    depositCount = 0
    totalDeposits = 0

    While Not (userResponse = "n")
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Desposit Amount:")
        If (depositAmount < 0 And depositAmount = 0) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Amount cannot be zero or negative.")
        Else
            depositAmount = Console.ReadLine()



            Console.WriteLine("Another (y or n)?")
            userResponse = Console.ReadLine()



            totalDeposits = totalDeposits + depositAmount
            depositCount = depositCount + 1
            averageDeposit = totalDeposits / depositCount

        End If
    End While


    Console.WriteLine("  Total deposits:               " + totalDeposits.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("  Number of deposits:           " + depositCount.ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("Average deposit:     " + averageDeposit.ToString)

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you very much problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to try: If (depositAmount < 0 or depositAmount = 0) From what I see the value cannot be negative and zero at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> It does not break when I enter a negative value or 0.
>   It does not show me the total values.

You're coding without your options turned on and trying to implicitly convert string to Decimal.  Also you're checking depositamount before the user enters it.

try something like this:

```
 Module Module1

 Sub Main()
    Dim userResponse As Char
    Dim depositAmount As Double
    Dim totalDeposits As Double

    Dim depositCount As Integer
    Dim averageDeposit As Double
    depositCount = 0
    totalDeposits = 0
While Not (userResponse = "n")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Desposit Amount:")
    'Attempt to convert readline to double. if it's successful GoodResponse
    'is true and depositamount has the value entered, otherwise it's 0
    Dim GoodResponse As Boolean = Double.TryParse(Console.Readline(), depositAmount)
    If Not GoodResponse OrElse depositAmount <=0 Then
        depositAmount = 0
        Console.WriteLine("Amount must be a number and cannot be zero or negative.")
    End If

        Console.WriteLine("Another (y or n)?")
        userResponse = Console.ReadLine()



        totalDeposits = totalDeposits + depositAmount
        depositCount = depositCount + 1
        averageDeposit = totalDeposits / depositCount

    End If
End While
```